# What does the $ sign mean when part of a file or folder name?

Tags: windows-7

I have folders that start with a `$`, like `$Recycle.Bin`, and folders that end with `$`, like `C$`.

Are these network shares?

Then again often I see files that otherwise look like dupes of files in the same folder, but they have a dollar sign somewhere in the name and they are greyed-out. What are those?

Answer (score 0):

Network shares ending in $ are hidden: `C$`, `IPC$`.

Folders and files with names starting with $ are not in any way special. You may create your own:

```
C:\Users\rpresser>del $foo

C:\Users\rpresser>echo this is a dollar file >$foo

C:\Users\rpresser>dir *foo*
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 0263-7E64

 Directory of C:\Users\rpresser

2021-08-31  04:52 PM                24 $foo
               1 File(s)             24 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  49,260,376,064 bytes free

C:\Users\rpresser>type $foo
this is a dollar file

C:\Users\rpresser>attrib $foo
A                    C:\Users\rpresser\$foo

C:\Users\rpresser>mkdir $bar

C:\Users\rpresser>dir *bar*
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 0263-7E64

 Directory of C:\Users\rpresser

2021-08-31  04:53 PM    <DIR>          $bar
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  49,260,335,104 bytes free

C:\Users\rpresser>
```

Note that this was done in a `cmd.exe` session. If you do it in PowerShell you will have trouble, because `$foo` will be interpreted as a variable reference.

Comment: in powershell just escape the `$` with backticks or single quotes: `mkdir '$bar'`

Answer (score -3):

The $ sign indicates that the folder is hidden. See
[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150118070115/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314984) for more information.

Comment: That article does not explain the $ in $Recycle.Bin though (which doesn't seem to be a hidden share)

Comment: This is completely wrong. Hidden is a filesystem attribute on Windows. The characters in the name don't affect the file's visibility so `$` is nothing special. OTOH file shares are different and they're not normal names